Polars - Issue with read_csv_batched when separator is included in the field
I am trying to read a relatively large csv +30M rows that cannot fit into memory so I am using read_csv_batched. However, I noticed that reader.next_batch(5) instead of returning number of batches dfs (in our case 5) it always returned 1 df with all the rows inside (bigger than the given batch size).
After some digging I created the following minimum example to reproduce the issue:
# error.csv
a,b
"test","test"
"test","test"
"test",",,"  # Notice here that we have 2 commas

# correct.csv
a,b
"test","test"
"test","test"
"test",","  # Here we only have 1 comma

reader_error = pl.read_csv_batched("./assets/error.csv", separator=",", batch_size=1, quote_char="\"")
batch = reader_error.next_batches(2)
print(len(batch))  # Prints 1, wrong

reader_correct = pl.read_csv_batched("./assets/correct.csv", separator=",", batch_size=1, quote_char="\"")
batch = reader_correct.next_batches(2)
print(len(batch))  # Prints 2, correct

Python: 3.10
Polars: 0.20.31

Any idea why this might be happening? Have I missed something about creating the csv correctly. I assumed that having anything inside " would be enough.
Many thanks!

Looks like a bug. If the result fits into memory, you could try scan_csv() + collect(streaming=True) instead.

Thanks for the suggestion! It kinda fits my purpose for now but non-streaming operators are bound to appear in what I am trying to do. I will wait for a bit and I might open an issue on github
